# how to import FaceBook profile pictures from album using Swift

Tags: facebook-graph-api, swift3

I am fetching the facebook profile picture like this

```
   let params = ["height": 300, "width": 300, "redirect": false] as [String : Any]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: params, httpMethod: "GET")
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("profile pic ************\(result)")
            }
        })
        connection.start()
```

Now I need to access the **profile pictures** from the **ablum** and set those in my **collectionView** . I tried to set the **graphPath: "me/album/profile_picture"** but no luck . Could anybody give me some hints please ?

Comment: What outputs in the console if you `print(error)`?

Comment: `Optional({
    data =     (
    );
})
`

Comment: Are you sure that's error or is that result?

Comment: its in `if error == nil {
                print("profile pic ************\(result)")
            }` , so its not error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the id of the `"Profile Pictures"` album and request the photos for that id.

```
Facebook.albums(user: "me").request({ albums in
    albums.first(where: { ($0["name"] as? String) == "Profile Pictures" }).flatMap({
        Facebook.photos(album: $0["id"] as! String).request({ photos in
            print(photos)
        })
    })
})
```

I have made an enum below to make requesting graph api paths easier.

```
enum Facebook: Graphable {

    case albums(user: String)
    case photos(album: String)

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case let .albums(uid):
            return "\(uid)/albums"
        case let .photos(aid):
            return "\(aid)/photos"
        }
    }

    var method: String {
        switch self {
        case .albums, .photos:
            return "GET"
        }
    }

    var params: [String : Any] {
        switch self {
        case .albums:
            return [:]
        case .photos:
            return [
                "height": 300,
                "width": 300,
                "redirect": false
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the protocol and extension the enum must conform to.

```
protocol Graphable {

    var path: String { get }
    var method: String { get}
    var params: [String : Any] { get }
}

extension Graphable {

    typealias JSON = [String:Any]

    func request(_ handler: @escaping ([JSON]!) -> (), failure: @escaping (Error) -> () = { print($0) }) {

        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(
            graphPath: path,
            parameters: params,
            httpMethod: method
        )

        connection.add(request) {
            _ = $0.1.map ({ handler(($0 as? JSON)?["data"] as? [JSON]) }) ??
                $0.2.map ({ failure($0) })
        }
        connection.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: dude , you are an angel from heaven :)

Comment: having some trouble in this line `_ = $0.1.map ({ handler($0 as! T) }) ??` , says **Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1058130b8) to 'NSArray' (0x105812c58)** , would you have some spare time to fix that !!

Comment: sorry dude I am bothering you much !!! Still having some issue, when I run the app it crashes and it shows me some thread issue like this : **libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC:** . I think its having trouble with the array

Comment: could you please help @Callam :(

Comment: yes its working now @Callam, I got the **id** of the photos . Thank you so much for your time and effort ,  it really helps. Thank you.

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING! Thank you!

Comment: After got album id, again request for the list of photos i got Optional({ data = ( ); }) empty array

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer like this :

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import SwiftyJSON   

func getFBAlbumID() {

let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums", parameters: nil, httpMethod: "GET")
let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
     if error == nil 
            let dictionary = JSON(result)
               // print("albums ID are **************\(dictionary)")
                if let data = dictionary["data"].array {
                    print("data of profilePicture ******* \(data)")

                    if let dict = data.first(where: { ($0["name"].string ) == "Profile Pictures" }) {
                        let id = dict["id"].string
                        print("my desired id : ********* \(id)")
                        self.getFBAlbumPhoto(albumID: id!)
                    }

                }
              }

        })
        connection.start()
}

func getFBAlbumPhoto(albumID: String) {


        let params = [ "height": 300, "width": 300, "redirect": false] as [String : Any]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(albumID)/photos?fields=source", parameters: params, httpMethod: "GET")
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //print(result)
                let dictionary = JSON(result)
                print("result are **************\(dictionary)")
            }
        })
        connection.start()

 }
```

Here I am grabbing the **ID** of the particular album I desire and then make another call to get the photos of that album. Here I am calling a function from inside another function. If someone can help me to write the code in more **Swift** way that would be helpful, like using closure. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Arafin, i got the nil response as Optional({
    data =     (
    );
})

Comment: after got album id, again request for the list of photos i got Optional({
    data =     (
    );
}) empty array